# From PySpark to SQL --- issues with rdd/pivot/case

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, lambda

I am having some problems creating a dynamic expression for sql in pyspark for pivoting purposes.

Here is my faulty code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Get distinct indicator values
indicators = [i.indicator for i in covid_df.select('indicator').distinct().collect()]
indicators = covid_df.toPandas()["indicator"].unique()
indicators = covid_df.select(F.collect_set("indicator").alias("column")).first()["column"]

# Generate pivot expressions dynamically
pivot_exprs = [F.sum(F.when(F.col("indicator") == ind, F.col("value"))).alias(ind) for ind in indicators]

# Construct the SQL query dynamically
query = """
    SELECT entity, iso_code, date, {}
    FROM covid
    GROUP BY entity, iso_code, date
    ORDER BY entity, date
""".format(", ".join(pivot_exprs))

# Execute the query
result = spark.sql(query)
result.show()
```

I have this dataset (plus 1000 more rows):

```
entity,iso_code,date,indicator,value
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-28,Daily ICU occupancy,41.0
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-28,Daily ICU occupancy per million,3.992
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-28,Daily hospital occupancy,402.0
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-28,Daily hospital occupancy per million,39.14
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-29,Daily ICU occupancy,43.0
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-29,Daily ICU occupancy per million,4.187
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-29,Daily hospital occupancy,403.0
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-29,Daily hospital occupancy per million,39.237
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-30,Daily ICU occupancy,42.0
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-30,Daily ICU occupancy per million,4.089
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-30,Daily hospital occupancy,403.0
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-30,Daily hospital occupancy per million,39.237
Portugal,PRT,2020-07-31,Daily ICU occupancy,41.0
```

and I would like to pivot the data either like this  --> this is WORKING :-)

```
query = """
    SELECT entity, iso_code, date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN indicator = 'Daily ICU occupancy' THEN value END) AS `Daily ICU occupancy`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN indicator = 'Daily ICU occupancy per million' THEN value END) AS `Daily ICU occupancy per million`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN indicator = 'Daily hospital occupancy' THEN value END) AS `Daily hospital occupancy`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN indicator = 'Daily hospital occupancy per million' THEN value END) AS `Daily hospital occupancy per million`,    
        SUM(CASE WHEN indicator = 'Weekly new ICU admissions' THEN value END) AS `Weekly new ICU admissions`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN indicator = 'Weekly new ICU admissions per million' THEN value END) AS `Weekly new ICU admissions per million`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN indicator = 'Weekly new hospital admissions' THEN value END) AS `Weekly new hospital admissions`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN indicator = 'Weekly new hospital admissions per million' THEN value END) AS `Weekly new hospital admissions per million`   
    
    FROM covid
    GROUP BY entity, iso_code, date
    ORDER BY entity, date
"""

sqltest = spark.sql(query)

sqltest.show()
```

or like this  --> this is also WORKING :-)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
    
    pivotdf = covid_df.groupBy(["entity", "iso_code", "date"]).pivot("indicator").sum("value").sort(["entity", "date"])
    
    pivotdf.limit(10).show()
```

but dynamically using sql, since I might not know the values under the "indicator" column.

I tried these three variations and all of them give same result:

```
v1 indicators = [i.indicator for i in covid_df.select('indicator').distinct().collect()]
v2 indicators = covid_df.toPandas()["indicator"].unique()
v3 indicators = covid_df.select(F.collect_set("indicator").alias("column")).first()["column"]

pivot_exprs = [F.sum(F.when(F.col("indicator") == ind, F.col("value"))).alias(ind) for ind in indicators]
```

Result from above pivot_exprs --> from variations:

```
[Column<'sum(CASE WHEN (indicator = Weekly new hospital admissions per million) THEN value END) AS `Weekly new hospital admissions per million`'>,
 Column<'sum(CASE WHEN (indicator = Weekly new ICU admissions) THEN value END) AS `Weekly new ICU admissions`'>,
 Column<'sum(CASE WHEN (indicator = Daily hospital occupancy per million) THEN value END) AS `Daily hospital occupancy per million`'>,
 Column<'sum(CASE WHEN (indicator = Daily hospital occupancy) THEN value END) AS `Daily hospital occupancy`'>,
 Column<'sum(CASE WHEN (indicator = Weekly new ICU admissions per million) THEN value END) AS `Weekly new ICU admissions per million`'>,
 Column<'sum(CASE WHEN (indicator = Daily ICU occupancy per million) THEN value END) AS `Daily ICU occupancy per million`'>,
 Column<'sum(CASE WHEN (indicator = Daily ICU occupancy) THEN value END) AS `Daily ICU occupancy`'>,
 Column<'sum(CASE WHEN (indicator = Weekly new hospital admissions) THEN value END) AS `Weekly new hospital admissions`'>]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So your question is how to simulate pyspark `.pivot()` function in SQL without using too many `CASE` statement?

Comment: yes... how many distinct values can be found in the column "indicator" is unknown, and each of those values will become columns!